# How to create a textarea in WiX using UI-Lib

Tags: html

This is weird. I went through the whole document **[Wix UI-lib](http://wix.github.io/wix-ui-lib/)** but could not find anything about how to create a textarea but `<textarea></textarea>`  won't work either. 
I am creating a setting view for my Wix Widget app.

Does anyone have any idea about how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attribute `data-ng-model="item.text"` to the textarea tag did it.

```
<textarea  data-ng-model="item.text"></textarea>
```

Thanks